# Mega menu : Sub menu items won't stay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to develop this mega menu like one at [Godaddy](http://pk.godaddy.com/). I have achieved this sliding down and sliding up effects etc. But I am not sure, how can I make this sub menu stay when an item from submenu is hovered, (For now, it slides the sub menu up as soon as I take my mouse out of the top menu item (as it should do because of the mouseout even))? My HTML and JS looks like:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
<ul class="group main-nav">
    <li><a href="#" data-subnav="define-subnav" class="nav-item">Definitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-subnav="voucher-subnav" class="nav-item">Vouchers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-subnav="final-subnav" class="nav-item">Final</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-subnav="reports-subnav" class="nav-item">Reports</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-down-content sub-nav">
    <li id="define-subnav">
        <div class="nav-item-content group">
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <h2>Definitions</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="voucher-subnav">
        <div class="nav-item-content group">
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <h2>Vouchers</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="final-subnav">
        <div class="nav-item-content group">
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <h2>Finals</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="reports-subnav">
        <div class="nav-item-content group">
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <h2>Reports</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-chunk">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Godown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.main-nav>li>a').on('mouseover', function (){
        var navContentId = $(this).data('subnav');
        $('#'+navContentId).slideDown();    
    });

    $('.main-nav>li>a').on('mouseout', function (){
        var navContentId = $(this).data('subnav');
        $('#'+navContentId).slideUp();  
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/G6Dyn/

Comment: Just remove `mouseout` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, making the submenu `stop` and `slideDown` on `mouseover` and `stop` and `slidUp` on `mouseout` worked for me. Here is what I mean to say:

```
$('.sub-nav>li').on('mouseover', function (){
    $(this).stop().slideDown();
});

$('.sub-nav>li').on('mouseout', function (){
    $(this).stop().slideUp();
});
```